# export 'userForm' (imported as 'userForm') was not found in '../form/userForm' (possible exports: default) in React

Tags: reactjs

I am making an application with React, I have created the file userForm.js, when I want to import it in another js file it gives me an error.
Here I put the code of the userForm:

```
    import { useState } from 'react';

const useForm = (initialValues) => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-useless-escape
    const emailRegex = /^(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})$/i;

    const [values, setValues]  = useState(initialValues);
    const [errors, setErrors ] = useState({});

    const onChangeField = (event) => {
        const { name, value } = event.target;
        console.log(name,values);
        setValues({
            ...values,
            [name]: value
        });
    validate({ [name]: value });
    }

    const onChangeFileField = (event) => {
        const { name, files } = event.target;
        console.log(name, files);
        setValues({
            ...values,
            [name]: files
        });
        validate({ [name]: files });
    }

    const getErrors = (inputValues = values) => {
        let newErrors = {...errors, isValid: true};

        if ("name" in inputValues) {
            newErrors.name = "";
            if (!inputValues.name || inputValues.name.length === 0) {
              newErrors.name = 'You must write the name';
              newErrors.isValid = false;
            }
            if (inputValues.name.length > 50) {
                newErrors.name = 'Name must be less than 50 characters';
                newErrors.isValid = false;
            }
        }

        if ("gender" in inputValues) {
            newErrors.genero = "";
            // eslint-disable-next-line eqeqeq
            if (!inputValues.gender || inputValues.gender == '') {
              newErrors.gender = 'You must indicate the gender';
              newErrors.isValid = false;
            }
        }

        if ("description" in inputValues) {
            newErrors.description = "";
            if (!inputValues.description || inputValues.description.length === 0) {
              newErrors.description = 'You must write the description';
              newErrors.isValid = false;
            }
            if (inputValues.description.length < 25) {
              newErrors.description = 'The description must be greater than 25 characters'
              newErrors.isValid = false;
            }
        }

        if("email" in inputValues){
            newErrors.email ="";
            // eslint-disable-next-line eqeqeq
            if(!inputValues.email || inputValues.email == ""){
                newErrors.email = 'You must write the email';
                newErrors.isValid = false;
            }
      
            if(!emailRegex.test(inputValues.email)){
                newErrors.email = 'The email is not correct';
                newErrors.isValid = false;
            }
        }
        return newErrors;
    }
    const isValid = () => {
        const errors = getErrors();
        return errors.isValid;
    }
    const validate = (inputValues = values)  => {
        const errors = getErrors(inputValues);
        setErrors(errors);
    }
    return  [
        values,
        errors,
        onChangeField,
        onChangeFileField,
        isValid,
        validate,
    ];
}

export default useForm;
```

Here I put the code of the file in which I want to import the userForm:

```
import Avatar from '@mui/material/Avatar';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import EditIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Edit';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Container from '@mui/material/Container';
import { FormControl, InputLabel, MenuItem, Select, Stack } from '@mui/material';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { userForm } from '../form/userForm';
import { addPiece, updateImage } from '../firebase/firebase';


export default function NewImagen(){
    const initialValues = {
        name: "",
        gender:"",
        description:"",
        image:""
    }

    const [values, errors, onChangeField, onChangeFileField, isValid] = userForm(initialValues);

    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (isValid()) {
            try{
                const image = await updateImage(values.image[0]);
                const doc = {
                    name: values.name,
                    gender: values.gender,
                    description: values.description,
                    image: values.image[0].name
                }
                await addPiece(doc);
                console.log('Has been added successfully');
                navigate('/Home/Gallery');
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
        }
    };

    const Input = styled('input')({
        display: 'none',
    });

    return (
        <Container component="main" maxWidth="lg" style={{ background: '#FFFFFF'} } >
            <CssBaseline />
            <Box
                sx={{
                    marginTop: 8,
                    display: 'flex',
                    flexDirection: 'column',
                    alignItems: 'center',
                  }}
            >
                <Avatar sx={{ m: 1, bgcolor: 'secondary.main' }}>
                    <EditIcon />
                </Avatar>
                <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
                    New Image 
                </Typography>
                <Box component="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit} noValidate sx={{ mt: 1 }}>
                    <TextField
                        margin="normal" required fullWidth value = {values.name}
                        onBlur = {onChangeField} onChange = {onChangeField}
                        id="email" label="Name" name="name"
                        autoFocus
                        {...(errors['name'] && { error: true, helperText: errors['name'] })}
                    />
                    <FormControl fullWidth >
                        <InputLabel id="gender">Gender</InputLabel>
                        <Select
                            labelId="gender" required fullWidth
                            id="gender" label="gender"
                            name="gender" onBlur = {onChangeField}
                            value={values.gender} onChange={onChangeField}
                            {...(errors['gender'] && {error: true})}

                        >
                            <MenuItem value="">Video game</MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem value={1}>Action</MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem value={2}>Arcadian</MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem value={3}>Strategy</MenuItem>
                        </Select>
                    </FormControl>
                    <TextField
                        margin="normal" required fullWidth
                        value={values.description} onBlur = {onChangeField}
                        onChange={onChangeField} name="description"
                        label="Description" multiline rows={4}
                        id="description"
                        {...(errors['description'] && { error: true, helperText: errors['description'] })}
                    />
                    <Stack direction="row" alignItems="center" spacing={2}>
                        <label htmlFor="contained-button-file">
                            <Input accept="image/*" 
                                id="contained-button-file"  multiple
                                name="image" onChange={onChangeFileField}
                                type="file" 
                            />
                            <Button variant="contained" component="span">
                                Up
                            </Button>
                            <Typography component="span" sx={{m:1}}>
                                {values.image && values.image[0].name}
                            </Typography>
                        </label>                
                    </Stack>
                    <Button
                        type="submit" fullWidth disabled={!isValid()}
                        variant="contained" sx={{ mt: 3, mb: 2 }}
                    >
                        Save
                    </Button>
                </Box>
            </Box>
        </Container>
    );
}
```

And the error that appears is the following:

```
ERROR in ./src/components/NuevoJuego.js 29:70-78
export 'userForm' (imported as 'userForm') was not found in '../form/userForm' (possible exports: default)
```

My question is if you could tell me why the error appears since I have the code correctly created.

Comment: You export `useForm` but try to import `userForm`, and also you `export default`, so you need to import it without the braces.

Comment: Not related with your question, this const `getErrors = (inputValues = values)` may become a problem. Since you use dynamic state without useCallback.